# Laravel chartisan chart git repository not found

Tags: php, laravel, charts, composer-php, packagist

I am using Chartisan chart in my project. Now when I run composer install it returns this error.

**fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Chartisan/Charts.git/' not found**

Now I have been stuck now because I didn't able to install packages.
any one else face this issue ?[image]

Comment: repository is private or owner removed this [use this](https://charts.erik.cat/installation.html#composer)

Comment: I tried to install this package but this returns error "zsh: no matches found: consoletvs/charts:6.*"

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old issue, this repo is no more accessable

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/chartisan-laravel-charts-consoletvscharts-broken